# Alignment issue in the Jobs page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design

There is a minor alignment issue in the Stack Overflow [Jobs page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/why-jobs). In bottom of the page, the **Search jobs** button is not properly aligned with the adjacent textboxes.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Search jobs button]

Configurations:

**Browsers:** Mozilla Firefox 58.0b9 (32-bit), Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**OS:** Windows 7, Windows 8
**Zoom:** 100%

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome.